# Implementing a two layered neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I've just started learning tensorflow on my own, and have tried to implement a two layered network but I cant seem to get it to work. Could you guys possibly point out what I'm currently doing wrong in my code below? Thank you.

```
# Hidden layer and output layer
hidden_node = 20
output_node = 10

# Weights and biases for layer one
layer1_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, hidden_node]))
layer1_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_node]))
# Weights and biases for layer two
layer2_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(hidden_node, output_node))
layer2_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_node]))

# Hidden and output layer
input = tf.matmul(mnist_dataset, layer1_weight) + layer1_bias
hidden = tf.nn.relu(input)
ouput = tf.matmul(hidden, layer2_weight) + layer2_bias
output_layer = tf.nn.softmax(output)

scores = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_node])
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
                      (output_layer, mnist_labels))
# Optimizer.
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: When I try to run my code it return errors: TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type bool that does not match type float32 of argument 'a'. ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype bool

Comment: There is a lot of help content in the TF docs and many many samples/examples in the TF repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a set of brackets here:

```
layer2_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(hidden_node, output_node))
```

Should be:

```
layer2_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_node, output_node]))
```